# JQuery cycle complication

Tags: jquery, cycle, carousel

I have played around and implemented JQuery cycle to create a carousel with images, but as yet, no HTML content. I know it works with HTML as per the demo at the bottom of the page

http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/int2.html

but because it parses child DIVS separately as individual slides, the HTML content can't include any DIVS. Is there a way of positioning content inside the DIV using something other than a DIV?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the [options page](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/options.html), you'll see an entry for `slideExpr` with the comment "expression for selecting slides (if something other than all children is required)". So you can just give all the top-level slide containers a class (like `slide` for example) and then pass that in:

```
$('#slideshow').cycle({ slideExpr: '.slide' });
```

Though it looks like the default is "all children", so sub-divs should not be a problem even under the default setup. The [source code](http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle.all.js) confirms this:

```
var $cont = $(this);
var $slides = opts.slideExpr ? $(opts.slideExpr, this) : $cont.children();
```

If you pass in a slide expression, it uses that, otherwise it uses `children()`, which only navigates a single level down.

Comment: Thanks. I had read a comment from the developer that I may have misinterpreted - either that or this is a more recent addition. Either way, I appreciate your help. JQuery cycle was able to do everything I needed except this, until now.